# problem on convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\tan^{-1} \frac1n\right)^a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Finding the set of all positive values of $a$ for which the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\tan^{-1} \frac1n\right)^a
$$ converges.
How will it depend on the the value of a that is its power of the term?
After expanding the arc tan term I get the form of summation of $[ -1/n^3(1/3+1/n^2+......]^a $. now how does it depend on a ?

Comment: On this website you're generally expected to write out your questions rather than inserting a picture, so that they can be found by search engines and hence more easily serve as future references

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to type this symbols

Comment: I guess $\tan^{-1}$ is nothing else than $\arctan$ ... This said, if you know that $\arctan(t)\underset{0}{=}t-\frac{t^3}{3}+o(t^3)$, you are almost done.

Comment: Yes I got it. After solving the numerator should not have power less than1 otherwise it will diverge. It should be greater than equal to 1 so a will be greater than equal to 1/3. Am I right?

Comment: @shadow kh that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use a Taylor series expansion, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\arctan \frac1n=\frac1n+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
$$  giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left(\frac1n-\arctan \frac1n\right)^a=O\left(\frac1{n^{3a}}\right)
$$ I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you don't ask for which values of $a$ the series converges, here is an heuristic answer.*

When $n$ goes to $\infty$, $\frac 1n$ goes to $0$ so $\tan^{—1}(1/n)$ goes to $0$.

So the general term (without the "$a$") of your series goes to $0$, so there is a reasonable chance that the series will converge.

It will converge if the general term goes to $0$ sufficiently fast.

That would be the case if $a$ is sufficiently big, but it won't be the case if $a$ is too small.